# Slider's background changes while scrolling the page,How Could it be possible

Tags: css, background

Please take a look at this website :

http://psnprofiles.com/

How does the slider's background work? I think it's a div but how do you place it behind everything else and as you scroll down you see an effect on the slider's background picture how can I make my slider's background like that,to change while someone is scrolling the page down.

Comment: You can use `z-index` to adjust order of display of elements on the page http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp. Otherwise your question is really broad and you're not going to get an answer for that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is a jQuery scroll script. In that page, see down the bottom

```
if ($('#slider'))
            {
                $(window).scroll(function(e)
                {
                    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
                    if (scrollTop <= 520)
                    {
                        if (scrollTop < 60)
                        {
                            scrollTop = 60;
                        }
                        $('#slider').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0,'+Math.floor((scrollTop-60)/2)+'px, 0)').css('-moz-transform', 'translate3d(0,'+Math.floor((scrollTop-60)/2)+'px, 0)');
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is what causes that behavior. You can also use scripts like [Stellar](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) , [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) and many more. It's called Parallax scrolling

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `z-index` for divs to show over each other

```
 .divClass{
    z-index: x ;

 }
```

note: x is a number.

if you have two divs with two different classes like these:

```
 .divClass1{

   z-index:100;
 }

 .divClass2{

   z-index:101;
 }
```

`.divClass2` is shown over `divClass1`

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index`

```
#divid
{
    z-index: 100;
}

#divid div
{
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: Z-index is just an int, no need for 'px'.